# переход на другую страницу php

Tags: php, header

Скажите, как при авторизации юзера правильно переходить на другую php страницу?
Вот у меня есть код на странице логина, как только я обновляю страницу, все ок, переходит на нужную страницу, а как сделать так чтоб при вводе логина и пароля, так же кидало на другую страницу. Пробовал тем же header, но ошибка

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
```

вот сам код

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['logged_user'])) {
         header ('Location: admpanel.php');
 echo '
 Авторизован!
 <hr>
 <a href ="./logout.php">Выйти</a>';
 exit;}
  $data=$_POST;
  if (isset($data['do_login']))
  {
    //проверка на юзера
    $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $data[login];
    echo 'юзер '.$_SESSION['logged_user'];
    header ('Location: admpanel.php'); 
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать header(), то нельзя ничего выводить на страницу до этого - это ограничение протокола http. Собственно, об этом и написано в сообщении об ошибке.

Уберите все echo.

Comment: спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, его стоит отметить галочкой как принятый. Это поможет другим посетителям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.